# How to create single chart with data from many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to plot a graph with data from several worksheets into the same chart. So each sheet's data would be a separate series in my chart. Here is the sample code for 2 sheets :

```
Name1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
Name2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Name

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'" & Name1 & "'!$C$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & Name1 & "!A1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & Name1 & "'!$C$" & nStart & ":$C$" & nLast & ""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & Name1 & "'!$E$" & nStart & ":$E$" & nLast & ""

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'" & Name2 & "'!$C$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='" & Name2 & "'!$C$" & nStart & ":$C$" & nLast & ""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & Name2 & "'!$E$" & nStart & ":$E$" & nLast & ""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & Name2 & "!A1"
```

But im getting an "Invalid parameter" error in the 2nd series collection. Please help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the line of code in your second series collection `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'" & Name2 & "'!$C$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "")` and see if it works then.

Since you are specifically defining the values for the series you don't even need the first `ActiveChart.SetSourceData` line of code.

You can also add these lines of code to give the graph a name, as it is overwritten when you add the second series;

```
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
Selection.Caption = "NameOfChart"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! Removing the 'ActiveChart.SetSourceData' line works